# How to make a output console using TextArea

Tags: java, console, textarea, javafx

I have to make an output console for my application. All the logging (user messages) will be displayed on that console. I have used `TextArea` for this purpose and I have used `TextArea.append()` method to continuously update the console. Further I am writing the console in a thread to keep the UI updated.

When the data is small it works fine. The problem arises when data on the console gets large; the screen begins to hang up.

Please suggest what should I do to overcome this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to other console behaviors e.g. eclipse, command line etc, find out your working threshold of the size. **Once you reach that size, truncate the contents from the beginning before appending the new contents in the end.**

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Actually the console information will be reviewed to verify the process, therefore the complete output is required.